# Method argument type based on previous argument return type

Tags: typescript

I have the following method (without type, since this is what this question is about):

```
export const mockSelector = (selector, matchers, returnValue) => {
    // Implementation
}
```

In this method, `selector` is a method that returns a value and `returnValue` is, well, the mocked return value I want to configure. It is used like so: `mockSelector(timerStoppedAtForPlayerSelector, [player.id, timerType], null)`.

**The core of my question is**: how can I make is to the type of `returnValue` is whatever the return type of `selector` is? In other words, if the selector I'm mocking is `() => 'Hello'`, then TS would error if anything other than a `string` is given for `returnValue` and if selector is `() => 42`, then TS would error if `returnType` is not a `number`.

I thought about using a generic to type the arguments, but the issue I encounter is that whenever the signature of `selector` changes, TS won't warn me about it.

This is the closest I think I got:

```
export const mockSelector = (selector: <T>(...args: any[]) => T, matchers: unknown[], returnValue: ReturnType<typeof selector>) => {
    // Implementation
}
```

However, using it causes this error: `TS2345 Argument of type A is not assignable to parameter of type A`.

Comment: Where is that error?  Please consider posting a [mcve] that others can drop into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue to themselves.

Comment: I might be missing something, but surely you;re already typing `selector` to return `T`, so the return type is... `T`?

Comment: Sure, I'll update with one.

Comment: @OlivierRadini: yes, but type T is not usable to type the `returnValue` argument.

Comment: @gCardinal Isn't it? I think it is if you move the generic definition [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYQQawMrAA2wCM0cAvHADwAqANHAKoB8AFKkSWVAFxxsAdMICGUAOap+I5AE8A2gF0AlJRZwGcDCJgIAFsChS4AV2Q5kEAO7IljKMBgmoyAGojCJ4P1qqK6gG8AKDhQuAB6cLgASQwwYgxgZBgdAEsUIIBfIA)

Comment: @OlivierRadini: Oh. Shows how much I still have to learn, I didn't know you could define a generic like this, **not** call it like so: `mockSelector<string>(selectorA, [], 42)` and still have TS be smart enough to figure out what the type of `returnValue` should be based on the `selector` argument's  return type. Dang.

Guess it was a silly question even though I thought I had tried everything. Thanks.

Comment: @gCardinal No silly questions, especially with TS. It can be a little sensitive about where you put things but I'm very often surprised how powerful it is. There are some super helpful people who answer questions here though who have helped me learn the language, would recommend posting questions like this if you're looking to figure the language out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a generic type parameter for that:

```
function mock<T>(selector: () => T, returnValue: T) {

}
```

That way you're "connecting" return type of the selector function and the returnValue parameter.

Comment: Thanks, @OlivierRadini also pointed me in the right direction. Didn't know you could "connect" types like this. I thought as soon as you defined a generic, you had to specify it when invoking the method.